# Gradients or y/x at that point

Tags: electrical-resistance

So, my teacher usually uses the gradient of graphs the find a lot of variables - e.g. Resistance of fixed resistor in V/I graph or Plancki's constant (divided by e) on a V/f graph.

My question is: should you rather be finding the y/x at a particular point on the best fit line since (for example) resistance is a certain voltage divided by a certain current rather than the change in voltage over change in current?

Some sites say that you use gradient if the graph is linear and calculations at a certain point if non-linear, but should the linear graph need to be passing through the origin too? Since the gradient would be (V2-V1)/(I2-I1) and since the origin is (0,0) substituting V1 and I1 for 0,0 respectively would get (V2-0)/(I2-0)=V2/I2... basically dividing voltage by current at certain point - does this prove that dividing voltage by current at a certain point on the best fit lineis the most reliable way to calculate these measurements such as resistance and Plancki's constant?

Answer (score 1):

Technically what you should use is

$$
s(x_1) = \lim_{x_2 \to x_1} \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_1 - x_2}
$$

That is, take both both points $x_2$ and $x_1$ arbitrarily close to each other. If the relation between $y$ and $x$ is linear $y = \alpha x + \beta$ note that the above equation becomes

$$
s(x_1) = \lim_{x_2 \to x_1} \frac{(\alpha x_2 + \beta) - (\alpha x_1  + \beta)}{x_2 - x_1} = \lim_{x_2 \to x_1} \frac{\alpha(x_2 - x_1) }{x_2 - x_1} = \alpha
$$

---

**EDIT**

To address some of the OP's concerns consider a [varistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varistor), an element commonly used to protect circuits against high voltages. The current-voltage curve for this element looks like this

[image]

And this is the idea:

- Imagine you are operating at the point I marked as $A$ ($V = 275$ V, $I = 7.5 {\rm m}A$). If you were to calculate the resistance as $V/I$ you would get

$$
R_{\rm ohm} = \left.\frac{V}{I}\right|_{A} = 36.52~{\rm k}\Omega
$$

- For voltages above $\sim250$ V in this example, a small change in voltage represents a large change in current. That is, the element behaves as it didn't have any resistance associated with it!

$$
R_{\rm actual} \approx 0
$$

Based on this results, which resistance would you associate to the element when operating at $A$?

Comment: Note that for most materials, voltage is linear with current (as is required by Ohm's Law; such materials are aptly called "Ohmic").

Comment: So gradient at certain point? Rather than y/x at certain point?

Comment: @kev correct, it is the gradient

Comment: Even when resistance measures the voltage divided by the current at a certain point in time rather thanthe changes in voltage divided by change in current? I read online on a few sites that it should be voltage divided by current at a certain point but I'm not sure when I can use the gradient as some sites say it is when thegraph is linear but I'm not 100% sure why when only linear

Comment: @kev In a linear resistor $V = I R$ ($\alpha = R$ and $\beta = 0$), so the equation above gives the same results. If  $\beta != 0$ you *can't* just divide $y/x$

Comment: @caverac But isn't the definition of resistance by ohm's law voltage divided by resistance? So like by finding the conductance of a diode at certain voltage on a I-V graph wouldn't you be finding the current divided by voltage at a certain point on the best fit curve rather than the tangent to the curve?

Comment: like on this video: https://youtu.be/45Rqrl9sSK4

Comment: @kev Updated the answer